# How to set up Webpack HMR services with a 3rd party web server

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, webpack-hmr

I am writing a React application, and using Webpack to break it up into chunks -- manifest, 3rd party, and multiple application chunks.

However, unlike a typical Webpack'ed application, I am not using Node to serve the chunks -- the web server is a custom built Golang server.  I will use [something] to make new bundles as source files are edited, and I have code in my Golang server that can watch for changes to the bundles.

But, I don't know what the client expects at runtime, in terms of how and what gets pushed by the server to the client.

Is there any documentation or example code that describes this process in sufficient detail?